# HTTP request not sending data properly

Tags: javascript, html, http, arduino

I made a simple JavaScript page that should display a timetable and send data via HTTP when the "Send" button is pressed.

Data should be sent to an Arduino using this simple scheme:

> http://arduinoip/DATASTARTSHEREhh:mm;hh:mm;hh:mm;[...];DATAENDSHERE

I print all the data I received in my Arduino serial monitor using the following code:

```cpp
void loop() {
  // listen for incoming clients
  EthernetClient client = ArduinoServer.available();
  String message = "";
  if (client) {
    Serial.println("new client");
    // an http request ends with a blank line
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        message += c;
        if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
          cmd = message.indexOf(DATASTARTING);
          Serial.print("CMD Value: ");
          Serial.println(cmd);
          if(cmd > 0){
            //I received some data and i want to know what it is.
            msg = message.c_str();
            char actChar = msg[cmd + 14]; //14 is the size of the string "DATASTARTSHERE"
            Serial.print("First character of data I'm interested in: ");
            Serial.println(actChar);
            int count = 0;
            values = "";
            while(actChar != 'D'){
              values += actChar;
              count++;
              actChar = msg[cmd + 14 + count];
            }
            Serial.print("Values i got: ");
            Serial.println(values);
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
            client.println("<html>");
            //client.println(params_to_html());
            client.println("I received data");
            client.println("</html>");
            Serial.println(message);
            break;
          }else{
            // send a standard http response header
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
            client.println("<html>");
            client.println("I didn't receive data");
            client.println("</html>");
            Serial.println(message);
            break;
          }
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
          // you're starting a new line
          currentLineIsBlank = true;
        }else if (c != '\r') {
          // you've gotten a character on the current line
          currentLineIsBlank = false;
        }
      }
    }
    // give the web browser time to receive the data
    delay(1);
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }  
}
```

The data I receive is the following:

> new client
>
> CMD Value: -1
>
> GET  /DATASTARTSHERE10:10;11:11;12:12;13:13;14:14;15:15;16:16;17:17;18:18;19:19;20:20;21:21;22:22;23:23;DATAENDSHERE HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: 192.168.1.32
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
>
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> client disconnected
>
> new client
>
> CMD Value: -1
>
> GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: 192.168.1.32
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
>
> Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Referer: 
>   http://192.168.1.32/DATASTARTSHERE10:10;11:11;12:12;13:13;14:14;15:15;16:16;17:17;18:18;19:19;20:20;21:21;22:22;23:23;DATAENDSHERE
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,
>
> client disconnected

Two things I don't understand:

1. Why do I get two responses? One with GET /whatisaftertheURL and one with GET /favicon.ico ?
2. Why `cmd` value is -1 even if I gave it the value of `indexOf(DATASTARTING)` when `DATASTARTING` is a `const char*` with `"DATASTARTSHERE"` value inside it?

If I delete some rows, like

```cpp
Serial.print("CMD Value: ");
Serial.print("First character of data I'm interested in: ");
Serial.println(actChar);
```

`cmd` becomes the right index of `DATASTARTSHERE` in the message, but I don't get what these rows got to do with the value of `cmd`, since it's compared before executing those lines.

I didn't manage to trigger it again, but adding some other rows to split the message, printing the message before it's split prints just half of the values I send in mi JS page.

This doesn't make sense for me, so is there a limit on what I can receive from a webpage?

I didn't post the code of my JS page because I found it unnecessary, but if it isn't I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers always make a request for Favicon.ico, read [this here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/web-security-appliance/117995-qna-wsa-00.html)

AFAIK you can stop it from happening but it isn't really necessary and can be safely ignored.

For your second question, `indexOf()` returns `-1` if the element is not found in the array or string so `message` does not contain `DATASTARTING` at the time you are checking.

It could be that `c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank` your first line in `c` is blank for some reason? But you should double check those values. I would remove the logic and just print those values as you iterate so you can get a better picture of what is happening.